# Can I remotely unlock my phone after I've remotely locked it?

Tags: security

Someone has stolen my phone s4 and is trying to extort me for 100 $.  If I remotely lock my phone can I unlock my phone remotely? to let him know that I'm going to shut it down if he doesn't act.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this. Locked my phone via desktop. From what I can tell, you can not remotely unlock. Not via device manage anyway. Not sure if there is another way, but I guess that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Do you mean cannot? Pretty important.

Comment: Yeah wow sorry. Haven't been on here in a long time. Fixed the typo.